# Visualize rasters as stacked layers

Tags: raster, visualisation

I have several raster files that are basically different indices produced with the same DEM. I want to visualize the raster layers in a way that the audience can see that they are stacked.

I am wondering is there a software that produces this effect?.

An example is given below (From Neon).

[image]

Comment: What software do you have? You could do it in ArcScene if you are using ESRI products.

Comment: mapview package in R has cubeView which is like this,